# What is this dipped powder cookie called?

Tags: cookies, food-identification

After hunting around online for "black and white cookies" and "powdered sugar and cocoa powder cookies", I can't find what kind of cookie I am looking for.

Not the black and white glazed cookie:

[image: Black and White Cookie]

I am thinking of a cookie I had as a kid that is made of a slightly sweet, heavy, and egg-sized lump of dough. The lump of dough is baked, and then one half is dipped in powdered sugar, and the other half is dipped in cocoa powder. Then you eat it.

If you can help me figure out what it is called, I can send pictures of the cookies once I make them :)

Comment: Are you thinking of a [Crinkle Cookie](https://www.google.com/search?q=crinkle+cookie&client=firefox-a&hs=k07&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=nts&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=1VE3VOTbA4KGjAKy7IGQCQ&ved=0CE0QsAQ&biw=1536&bih=731)? It's not *exactly* what you describe, but I could see your description being a family variation.

Comment: Can we all have a moment of silence for the Black and White cookie? What an invention that is.

Comment: And, if you ARE thinking of a Crinkle Cookie, the folks at Cook's Illustrated just recently posted their take on the classic cookie here:  http://www.cooksillustrated.com/recipes/8125-chocolate-crinkle-cookies

Comment: Sorry, not a crinkle cookie. The cookie I am thinking of has one half that is cocoa and one that is powdered sugar, not a chocolate cookie dipped in powdered sugar. That recipe does look good, though. :)

Comment: If not crinkle, how about [snickerdoodle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snickerdoodle)? Why not powder-coat before baking? After baking, if warm, your cookies will deform when dipped. If cold, your powder won't stick as well; hence crinkles and snickerdoodles and ginger cookie/snap are rolled in powder/granules before baking.

Comment: Can you edit the question with more description of the nature of the cookie? E.g., what kind of dough: Sugar cookie? Shortbread? Same as black-and-white? Contains egg? Other spices (nutmeg, cinnamon, ...)? Region of origin? That ilk might help. From comments, I glean only: drop cookie; not chocolate dough; dusted after baking with two powders.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it!

The recipe was in a book at my house called *Cookies* and published by Reader's Digest (ISBN: 0-7621-0593-3).

This recipe is typed up verbatim from the source mentioned above.

> **Two-Tone Cookies**
>
> 1 2/3 cups all-purpose flour
>
> 1 teaspoon baking powder
>
> 1/8 teaspoon salt
>
> 1/3 cup butter, softened
>
> 1/4 cup granulated sugar
>
> 2 large eggs
>
> 1 tablespoon milk
>
> 1/4 cup confectioners' sugar
>
> 1/4 cup unsweetened cocoa powder
>
> Preheat the oven to 350°F. Butter two cookie sheets. Sift the flour, baking powder, and salt into a large bowl and make a well in the center. Add the butter, sugar, eggs, and milk. Use your hands to knead the mixture into a smooth dough. Form the dough into balls the size of walnuts and place 1 inch apart on the prepared cookie sheets. Bake for 15-20 minutes, or until just golden, rotating the sheets halfway through for even baking. Transfer to racks and let cool completely. Dip half of each cookie in the confectioners' sugar and the remaining half in the cocoa.
>
> Makes 26 cookies. Prep: 35 min. Cooking: 15-20 min. Level: 1. Keeps 5 days.

I made the cookies a couple nights ago- they are a bit time-consuming to bake and dip, but I ended up with the cookies that I remembered- light and covered half with cocoa powder and half with confectioners' sugar. I used little bowls of powder to dip the cookies in. Here is a picture that I took of the finished cookie:

[image: two-tone cookie]

In terms of eating them, I recommend eating the entire cookie in one bite. If you decide to have a little nibble, you won't really enjoy the whole mixture of the flavors of the cocoa and the sugar at once :) Enjoy.

Comment: Cool! I'm glad you found it. It looks like the attempts weren't that far off.

Answer (score 3):

Your fond recollection sounds like a variation on the *Russian* tea cake. Here's the Betty Crocker [recipe](http://www.bettycrocker.com/recipes/russian-tea-cakes/3af8664b-6c3e-4022-b686-cd961521e59b) (and photo below).

[image: Russian Tea Cakes]

Now, without powdered sugar underneath, the cocoa-dipped end would probably have been bitter. So if you remember it as being sweet but just *less* sweet than the sugar-dipped end, it's very likely the cookie was first rolled entirely in powdered sugar (just as this recipe suggests) and then dipped in cocoa powder as a finishing touch . Also, if the size and shape varied a bit from what's in this photo, this was probably at your baker's discretion as it's easier to dip something a bit oblong than it is to dip something spheric.